# OpenGL quad appears black when using textures loaded with freeimage

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, freeimage

I'm using OpenGL 4.3 and I'm trying to draw a quad on which I would like to apply this texture (namely "textures/dickbutt.png"). The texture has 654x654 dimensions.

[image: dickbutt]

But every possible combinations of instructions always led me to have a black texture and sometimes with some artefacts on the lower right corner.

[image: black quad]
[image: artefacts close-up]

Here's the code of the main function in which the drawing occurs.

```
void Run() {
  shader::factory::CompileShaderFile("shaders/test.vert", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  shader::factory::CompileShaderFile("shaders/test.frag", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  GLuint m_shaderProgram = shader::factory::CreateProgram();

  // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
  GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f
  };

 GLfloat texcoords[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f
  };

  GLuint VBO, VAO;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glBindVertexArray(VAO);

  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  // Position attribute
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glBindVertexBuffer(0, VBO, 0, 3*sizeof(GL_FLOAT));
  glVertexAttribFormat(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
  glVertexAttribBinding(0, 0);

  GLuint texVBO;
  glGenBuffers(1, &texVBO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texVBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texcoords), texcoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  glBindVertexBuffer(1, texVBO, 0, 2 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT));
  glVertexAttribFormat(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
  glVertexAttribBinding(1, 1);

  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


  GLuint m_textureID = 
    texture::factory::Create2DTexture("textures/dickbutt.png");

  shader::module::RegisterUniform("mytexture", m_shaderProgram);

  while (!graphic_context->PollWindowClosedEvent()) {
    double dt = timer::chrono::GetTimeElapsedInSeconds();

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    shader::module::Use(m_shaderProgram);
    glUniform1i(shader::module::GetUniformLocation("mytexture", m_shaderProgram), 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Next line renders the XYZ axes in separated shader program, commenting it out changes nothing in the texture display.
    scene::Render(); 

    graphic_context->Update();
    timer::chrono::Update();
  }
}
```

Here's the code of the texture::factory where the image is loaded and the OpenGL buffer is created and setup.

```
GLuint Create2DTexture(const std::string& a_sFileName) {
  GLsizei wWidth, wHeight;
  unsigned char *wImage = nullptr;
  void *wBitMapHandle = nullptr;

  if (!LoadImage(a_sFileName, wImage, wWidth, wHeight, wBitMapHandle)) {
    std::cerr << "texture_factory::Create2DTexture -> Loading image failed. " << std::endl
      << "Returning 0xFFFFFFFF..." << std::endl;
    return 0xFFFFFFFF;
  }

  // Generate texture
  GLuint wTexture;
  glGenTextures(1, &wTexture);
  // Create texture
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, wTexture);

  glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,    // 2D texture target
    0,                // Base mipmap level
    GL_RGBA,           // RGBA color components
    wWidth, wHeight,  // Dimensions
    0,                // Must be 0...
    GL_RGBA,           // Pixel data format
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // Depends on what the LoadImage function return type
    wImage);          // Loaded image

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);          

  // Commenting-out the next line make the artefacts appear on the quad
  //  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  // Free image
  FreeImage(wBitMapHandle);
  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  return wTexture;
}
```

The LoadImage function

```
bool LoadImage(const std::string& a_sFileName,
  unsigned char *a_pImage,
  GLsizei& a_rWidth,
  GLsizei& a_rHeight,
  void *a_pBitmapHandle) {
  const char *wFilename = a_sFileName.c_str();
  //image format
  FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FIF_UNKNOWN;
  //pointer to the image, once loaded
  FIBITMAP *dib(0);
  //pointer to the image data
  BYTE* bits(0);
  //image width and height
  unsigned int width(0), height(0);

  //check the file signature and deduce its format
  fif = FreeImage_GetFileType(wFilename, 0);
  //if still unknown, try to guess the file format from the file extension
  if (fif == FIF_UNKNOWN)
    fif = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(wFilename);
  //if still unkown, return failure
  if (fif == FIF_UNKNOWN)
    return false;

  //check that the plugin has reading capabilities and load the file
  if (FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(fif))
    dib = FreeImage_Load(fif, wFilename);
  //if the image failed to load, return failure
  if (!dib)
    return false;

  //retrieve the image data
  bits = FreeImage_GetBits(dib);
  //get the image width and height
  width = FreeImage_GetWidth(dib);
  height = FreeImage_GetHeight(dib);
  //if somehow one of these failed (they shouldn't), return failure
  if ((bits == 0) || (width == 0) || (height == 0))
    return false;

  a_pImage = bits;
  a_rWidth = width;
  a_rHeight = height;
  a_pBitmapHandle = dib;

  return true;
}
```

And the related vertex/frag shader code respectively

```
// test.vert
#version 430
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texcoord;

layout (std140, binding = 0) uniform CameraInfo {
  mat4  ProjectionView; 
  vec3  eye;
};

out vec2 tex_coord;

void main()
{
  vec4 vertex = vec4(position,1.0);
  gl_Position = ProjectionView*vertex;
  tex_coord = vec2(texcoord.x, 1.0 - texcoord.y);
}

//test.frag
#version 430

out vec4 color;

in vec2 tex_coord;

// Texture samplers
uniform sampler2D mytexture;

void main()
{
    //color = vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); // Prints red quad
    color = texture2D(mytexture, tex_coord);
}
```

I compared the code dozens of times with tutorials, other posts on SO and working examples, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already passing `a_rWidth` and `a_rHeight` as references. You must equally do so for `a_pImage` and `a_pBitmapHandle`.

This all boils down to why something like this:

```
int a = 1;
test(a);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Prints `1` and not `2` given that `test()` is defined like this:

```
void test(int a) {
    a = 2;
}
```

Thus you need to change `LoadImage` to this:

```
bool LoadImage(
    const std::string &a_sFileName,
    unsigned char **a_pImage,
    GLsizei &a_rWidth,
    GLsizei &a_rHeight,
    void **a_pBitmapHandle) {

    [...]

    *a_pImage = bits;
    a_rWidth = width;
    a_rHeight = height;
    *a_pBitmapHandle = dib;
```

and call it like this:

```
LoadImage(a_sFileName, &wImage, wWidth, wHeight, &wBitMapHandle)
```

Additionally note that FreeImage decodes images into the BGR/BGRA format. So you have to use `GL_BGRA` instead of `GL_RGBA`.

Comment: Oh my god...you're completely right! NOTE: After correcting this, I had an access violation exception caused by glTexImage2D which I had to fix using ``FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits`` and use the proper parameters as you said (``GL_BGRA``). You made my week thank you!

Comment: Was actually thinking whether you needed `FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits` or not. Props to you for figuring it out. Anyways, you're welcome! :)